# I have a linked list, I would like to remove duplicate values

Tags: c, algorithm, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So, I've created a code where it creates a linked list with 5 values. I would like to know what would be the best method to remove duplicates of those values and print the linked list again without the duplicates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* self-referential structure*/
struct studentID{
    int value;          //a data member which is an integer
    struct studentID *next;         //a data member which is a pointer to next node
};


typedef struct studentID STUDENTID;     //creating a nickname for struct studentID as STUDENTID
typedef STUDENTID *STUDENTIDPtr;        //creating a nickname for STUDENTID as STUDENTIDPtr


//Global variables
STUDENTIDPtr previousPtr;           //pointer to previous node in list
STUDENTIDPtr currentPtr;            //pointer to current node in list


void printList(STUDENTIDPtr currentPtr){


    while (currentPtr != NULL){         //while not the end of the list
        printf("%d -> ", currentPtr->value);
        currentPtr = currentPtr ->next;
    }
}


int main(){
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr1;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr2;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr3;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr4;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr5;           //creating a pointer to create a new node


    //creation of the first node
    newPtr1 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr2 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr3 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr4 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr5 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created


    newPtr1 -> value = 4; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr1 -> next = newPtr2;


    newPtr2 -> value = 4; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr2 -> next = newPtr3;


    newPtr3 -> value = 5; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr3 -> next = newPtr4;


    newPtr4 -> value = 2; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr4 -> next = newPtr5;


    newPtr5 -> value = 1; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr5 -> next = NULL;


    currentPtr = newPtr1;

    printList(newPtr1);


    return 0;
}
```

will using if else and run through every linked list be easy or is there a better method?

Comment: It is unclear whether you mean adjacent duplicated elements or all duplicated elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches that come to mind right away, and which one to use depends on your specific case, and whether you'd like to preserve the original order of elements or not.

---

1st approach:

Use a double loop and pick up a node at a time. Then iterate the list after that node, and if you find a duplicate, remove. Repeat picking nodes, until you have iterated over the whole list.

```
For every node of the list
  For every next_node after node
    If next_node.value == node.value
      Remove that next_node
```

This approach preserves the original order of the elements.

This approach is I think what you'd have already in mind. I suggest you start with that.

Example:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1

I will start from the first node (1), check the second node, the third, the fourth, nothing so far, no duplicates found. I now check the fifth node, which also has the value 1 (duplicate found!), so I remove it.

Now the list looks like this:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Now I am looking of duplicates of the second node (I checked for the first node in the previous traversal). I check 3, I check 4, no duplicates found. The list remains the same.

Now I am looking of duplicates of the third node. I check 4, no duplicates found. The list remains the same.

Now I am looking of duplicates of the fourth node. The next node is NULL, which means that the fourth node is the last node (because we removed the fifth node in the first traversal, as a duplicate of 1). There is nothing to check then, the list remains the same:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Observe how, for every node that I want to check if duplicates exist, I traverse the list until its end. So, for every node, I am doing an O(N) traversal, where N is the size of the list.

How many nodes do I have? N

So the Time Complexity of this approach is N * O(N) = O(N<sup>2</sup>)

I strongly recommend trying that out yourself, and practice. When you are done, you could read the [Remove duplicates from an unsorted list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/) to check your solution.

---

2nd approach:

Sort the list, and now the list will have the duplicate values grouped together. So, if there is a duplicate of the current node, it will be its next node. If it's a duplicate, remove next node.

Now, again, if there is a duplicate of the current node, it will be its next node. So do the same above, until the next node is *not* a duplicate of the current node.

Then, make next node the current node, and do the same process.

```
Sort list
current_node = head_node
While current_node != NULL
  If current_node.value == current_node.next.value
    Remove current_node.next
  Else
    current_node = current_node.next
```

This approach does *not preserve* the original order of the elements.

Same Example:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1

Sort the list:

> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

I start from 1. I check its next node, it's also 1, a duplicate found! Remove the next node. Now the list is:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Current node is still 1. I check its next node, it's 2. Not a duplicate. List remains the same. Set next node as the current node.

Current node is 2. Check its next node, it's 3, not a duplicate. List remains the same. Set next node as the current node.

Current node is 3. Check its next node, it's 4, not a duplicate. List remains the same. Set next node as the current node.

Current node is 4. It doesn't have a next node, nothing to check, I am done. List remains the same:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Observe that for every node, I check only its immediate next node(s). And then, I continue for the last next node checked. That is O(N).

However, I had to sort the list, in order to ensure that the duplicates are grouped. Sorting a list can be done in O(NlogN).

The Time Complexity is O(NlogN) + O(N) = O(NlogN).

I had used Merge Sort to [sort the list in C](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-mergesort-c/). There is also the [Remove duplicates from sorted list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-a-sorted-linked-list/) for another explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try this one out ASAP. if i run into anything i'll just drop a comment back to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the posted code you are "manually" adding every node if front of the list, so the first step would be to create a function that does that.

Then, you can create another function that will add a node in a list keeping it sorted. It will traverse the list finding the right location and will add a node only if it is not already there another node with the same value.

Now you can traverse the original list (the one which is not sorted) and for every node, try to add a copy of it to the sorted list. If it's already there, remove the node from the original list, otherwise add the copy to the sorted list.

At the end you will have two lists of unique elements, one of which sorted.

Don't forget to create a function that releases the allocated memory.

Comment: Thank you, apparently for the creation of nodes I am not supposed to use functions nor loops, which is why i had to hard code the numbers (i didn't use a ```scanf``` as the numbers i enter are unique to myself) and it cannot be sorted as well because those numbers are supposed to be in a specific order as it is unique. I'll give yours a shot though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean to remove not only adjacent duplicate values in the list.

What you need is to write a function that will accept the head node of the list by reference. The function can return the number of removed nodes.

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to declare the global variables

```
//Global variables
STUDENTIDPtr previousPtr;           //pointer to previous node in list
STUDENTIDPtr currentPtr;            //pointer to current node in list
```

that moreover are redundant.

And this typedef can confuse readers of the code

```
typedef STUDENTID *STUDENTIDPtr;
```

Also you could write a separate function that adds a node to the list. You could initially to write the function such a way that the nodes in the list were ordered by the value.

As for the function that removes duplicate values then it can look the following way as iy is shown in the demonstrative program below. Investigate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* self-referential structure*/
struct studentID{
    int value;          //a data member which is an integer
    struct studentID *next;         //a data member which is a pointer to next node
};


typedef struct studentID STUDENTID;     //creating a nickname for struct studentID as STUDENTID
typedef STUDENTID *STUDENTIDPtr;  

size_t remove_duplicates( STUDENTIDPtr *head )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; *head != NULL; head = &( *head )->next )
    {
        for ( STUDENTIDPtr *next = &( *head )->next; *next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( ( *head )->value == ( *next )->value )
            {
                STUDENTIDPtr tmp = *next;
                *next = ( *next )->next;
                free( tmp );
                ++n;
            }
            else
            {
                next = &( *next )->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return n;
}

void printList(STUDENTIDPtr currentPtr){


    for ( ; currentPtr != NULL; currentPtr = currentPtr ->next )
    {
        printf("%d -> ", currentPtr->value);
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr1;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr2;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr3;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr4;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr5;           //creating a pointer to create a new node


    //creation of the first node
    newPtr1 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr2 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr3 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr4 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created
    newPtr5 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node is created


    newPtr1 -> value = 4; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr1 -> next = newPtr2;


    newPtr2 -> value = 4; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr2 -> next = newPtr3;


    newPtr3 -> value = 5; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr3 -> next = newPtr4;


    newPtr4 -> value = 2; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr4 -> next = newPtr5;


    newPtr5 -> value = 1; // assign data in first node 
    newPtr5 -> next = NULL;


    printList( newPtr1 );

    size_t n = remove_duplicates( &newPtr1 );

    printf( "There are removed %zu elements\n", n );

    printList( newPtr1 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
4 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL
There are removed 1 elements
4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL
```

Bear in mind that you need to write also a function that will free all allocated memory for the list.

Comment: apparently I have to use typedefs for this and also yes I am well aware that it is a bad practice to use global variables. but I used them first because I had an idea of using them in a process but didn't initiate it.

Also, the function can also be done using while loops instead of the for loops right?

Comment: @FAFSHOCK Pay attention to that it is only me who shows how the function can be written. Without my code you had big difficulties.L(

Comment: yeah, Thank you for that!

still new and learning code and when it comes to pointers and functions and such, it really gets me in trouble because i come across many pointer errors which i don't really know to counter. I'm just really not sure on using this method as I have not learned that you could use for-loops in that way (only method i have used is ```for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)```). which is why I'm trying with a while loop

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is only for sufficiently small integer values, not extremely large ones.
What we can do here is take another array that can act as associative container.

- Take an array. Initialize that array to 0.
- Start to traverse the linked list.
- if (arr[node->data] == 0); then increment arr[node->data]. This will make it 1, marking one occurrence.
- else if (arr[node->data] == 1); then delete this node, as this means that the current node already contains an integer that has been encountered before.

You can implement a DS based on hashing or BST's, similar to cpp maps, to act as associative container, if you want to scale this up.

If you want a generic algorithm, I would encourage that you first write a brute-force logic along following lines --

- Traverse the linked list
- if the 'data' is found for the first time, then ignore and continue.
- if the 'data' is found next time, invoke the logic of deletion.

Comment: At first using an array was my idea. as i run through a loop taking a single node comparing it with the rest. if it has no duplicates, it gets added to an array. but will it be a lengthy process is my fear.

Comment: umm.. not that way.. what I meant is - if your first node contains 1 as data, then the arr[1] = 1 should be done. Moving to the next node of the linked list, if it again has a 1, we have found a duplicate as the arr[1] is already 1. 
In this, you will traverse the linked list only once and find all the duplicates based on making the data in the node an index to the array; and marking the value at that index as 1, meaning 'already encountered'...